# Earth View in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the latest maps API and I was wondering how, if at all possible, can I enable the earth view for my map? What I'm looking for is the following result:

[image: first view]

...and after clicking the bottom left element 'Earth':

[image: second view]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The earth-view is not available in the Maps-Javascript-API-V3, you'll need to implement it on your own by using the [Earth-API](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index).

Basically you'll need to use 2 containers, 1 for the map and 1 for the earth. When you want to switch between map and earth you must toogle the visibility of the containers.

When you don't want to reinvent the wheel you may use this library: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/docs/reference.html

Comment: I see. What I don't understand is how come in maps switching to earth view happens without a google earth plugin for the browser, while in the examples that I found (which are in the general lines as your proposed approach) a plugin is needed.

Comment: The earth-view in maps.google.com uses WebGL. Currently there is no API available so you must use what is available:the API for the earth-plugin.

Comment: Right. Thx for the answr.